# How to test for model type in Angular 2 Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

We want to test a return type of a method of a service. Let's say that the GetItems() returns an array of Items.

We can't figure out how to test for this. If we do this:

```
expect(service.getNavItems()).toEqual(jasmine.any(Array));
```

It  passes...however if we do this

```
expect(service.getNavItems()).toEqual(jasmine.any(Item[]));
```

There must be a simple way to test for a return type (of something that is not built in such as Number or Array).

Thanks.
M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Model
export class SomeModel {
  constructor(
    public name: string = "") { }
}

// Spec
it('Should return SomeModel[]', () => {
  const items = service.getItems();

  items.forEach(item => {
    expect(item instanceof SomeModel).toBe(true, 'instance of SomeModel');
  });
});
```